# Why does "Set" operate differently in a Swift Playground?

Tags: swift, duplicates, set

If I run the following code in a Swift playground it works as expected. That is, the "equatable" object is added only once, and "==" operator is called. However, if I paste the code in an app it adds the object twice.  I gather I'm missing something obvious.

Xcode 11.5, Swift version 5.2.4.

Any help appreciated.

```
struct Object: Equatable, Hashable {
    let name: String
    let completed: Bool  
    static func == (lhs: Object, rhs: Object) -> Bool {
        // Comparison operator called only in playground
        print("Comparing \(lhs.name) == \(rhs.name)")
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
    }
}
let firstObject = Object(name: "apples", completed: false)
let secondObject = Object(name: "apples", completed: true)
var set = Set<Object>()
set.insert(firstObject)
// set.insert(secondObject) // Adds "duplicate" object
set.update(with: secondObject) // Also adds "duplicate" object
print(set) // Why are two "equal" objects added to the set?
```

Playground output:

```
Comparing apples == apples
[__lldb_expr_5.Object(name: "apples", completed: true)]
```

App output:

```
[settest.ViewController.(unknown context at $106fd87bc).(unknown context at $106fd8808).Object(name: "apples", completed: false), settest.ViewController.(unknown context at $106fd87bc).(unknown context at $106fd8808).Object(name: "apples", completed: true)]
```

Also, if I add more properties or change the `Bool` to `String` the result is the same.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this in an actual project, but only if I put the `Object` struct declaration inside the function of the view controller I'm testing this out on (`viewDidLoad` in my case). As soon as I move the struct's declaration outside of the function (either inside the view controller's declaration as a nested type or just global scope), then the problem goes away.

Comment: Ok, I see it works for me as well if I move the `Object` definition. Thanks, Tyler. I hadn't tried that  yet :)

Comment: No prob. Yeah I have no idea why it behaves like that when you have the struct defined inside the function. I'm guessing it's a bug in Swift.

Comment: It's the same for me, but in a playground, so yes maybe a swift bug, but Xcode is fine

Comment: I’m not entirely surprised at this but it’s still a great bit of detective work. The reason I’m not surprised is that there’s something odd about the idea of `static` in a purely local and temporary object type. Solution: don’t do that. Local structs are cool but I guess they can’t do everything. Still, file a bug and see what happens.